# MAAS - configure raid via Web-UI

Tags: maas

how is it possible to configure a raid setup for a machine using the web-ui? For the moment, the RAID configuration is directly done using the bios, but I wonder how that could be accomplished using the web-ui as well? The buttons are there, but disabled.

[image: Web-UI showing buttons to configure RAID]

Comment: "For the moment, the RAID configuration is directly done using the bios, but I wonder how that could be accomplished using the web-ui as well?" - the answer is "don't use RAID" - the point of MAAS is for better compute and IO performance, not RAID. (Also, "rapid set-up" implies "disposable machine" which in-turn implies the machine simply won't be around long-enough for an unlikely disk failure event to happen in the first place - also on Linux you'd be using OS-provided redundant disk support like ZFS (which is generally fungible) instead of non-portable and proprietary local hardware RAID.

Comment: RAID can be hardware or software based. 

MAAS can handle only the software one. If you are interested in the hardware RAID, you have to configure it with your BIOS/UEFI/Management tool from your machine vendor.